# get fields from redis hash key start with some common text

Tags: redis, hash

I want to fetch all fields from redis hash key which are start with some string

for example
hash key contains fields
studentA001
studentB253
studentA24165

so I want all field which start with studentA

I trying to all keys and check if it contains or start with docID

```
try (Jedis jedis = this.getJedisPool().getResource()) {
            Set<String> keys = jedis.hkeys(mapKey);
            for (String key : keys) {
                if (StringUtils.contains(key, docId)) {
                    long clearedCount = jedis.hdel(mapKey, key);
                    if (clearedCount > 0) {
                        cacheCleared = true;
                        log.info("Cleared from cache for Doc ID: [" + docId + "");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan/) command with the optional `[MATCH pattern]` argument.

Here is an example:

```
redis> HSET h student1 dave student2 joe teacher1 john
(integer) 3
redis> HSCAN h 0 MATCH student*
1) "0"
2) 1) "student1"
   2) "dave"
   3) "student2"
   4) "joe"
```

Comment: yes I tried that as well using java but not get the results

Comment: It should work... Please share your code in the question.

Comment: try (Jedis jedis = this.getJedisPool().getResource()) {
    ScanResult<Entry<String, String>> keys = jedis.hscan(mapKey, "0", new ScanParams().match(docId + "*"));

    if (keys != null) {
     List<Entry<String, String>> result = keys.getResult();
     result.forEach(entry -> {
      log.info("Clearing cache for: " + entry.getKey());
     });
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
   }